# Using Laws of Big O

Tags: big-o

Let's say the question that I wish to answer is:

**Q. Prove that O(n) + O(1) = O(n)**

And I answered the question like so...

First of all we can see that *f(n) < f(n) + 1 < 2f(n)* thus we can state that *O(n) + O(1) = 2O(n)* and then by applying the coefficient rule we have *O(n) + O(1) = O(n)*.

I am trying to understand how to correctly tackle these kind of questions and was wondering if my reasoning is correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to elaborate more by proving:

1. `O(n) <= O(n) + O(1)`
2. `O(n) + O(1) <= O(n)`

and then concluding that both sets are the same (you can think of these *objects* as sets of functions and inequalities between them as inclusions).

**Inequality 1**

Take `f(n)` in `O(n)`. We have to prove that `f(n)` can be expressed as a function in `O(n)` plus a function in `O(1)`. This is true because `f(n) <= f(n) + 1` (your argument).

**Inequality 2**

Take two functions `f(n)` in `O(n)` and `g(n)` in `O(1)`. We have to show that `f(n) + g(n)` is in `O(n)`. In other words, we have to show that `f(n) + g(n) <= C*n` for some constant `C` and `n` large enough.

Now, we can use that there exist a constant `A` and an integer `N` such that `f(n) <= A*n` for `n > N`. This is because `f(n)` is in `O(n)`. Similarly, there exist `B` and `M` such that `g(n) <= B` for `n > M` (because `g(n)` is in `O(1)`). Therefore, for `n > max(N,M)` we get

```
f(n) + g(n) <= A*n + B
            <= max(A,B)*n + max(A,B)
            <= max(A,B)*n + max(A,B)*n
            <= 2max(A,B)*n
```

which shows that there is a constant `C`, namely, `2max(A,B)`, and an integer `R`, namely `max(N,M)` such that: `f(n) + g(n) <= C*n` for all `n > R`, which means by definition that `f(n) + g(n)` is in `O(n)`, as we wanted to see.